# Model properties not filled on jquery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, .net-5

I have a strange issue doing an ajax post.
The data is sent to the request, but for some reason the data does not arrive in the controller function.

This is my post function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            window.location.replace(data.redirect);
        } else {
            $(dest).replaceWith(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        //alert('Response code:' + xhr.status + '\r\n[Error:' + err + '] ' + status);
    }
});
```

Nothing too uch out of the ordinary there.
When I set a breakpoint in this function I do see the data I expect:
[image]

But when I arrive at my controller function the properties of the viewmodel aren't filled:
[image]

I've tried to add attributes to the parameter, like [FromBody] and sorts, but most of the time that results in a 415.

The date is retrieved with $("form").serialize() if that would make a difference.

I've used the function in the past, when I was still using plain MVC, and this worked back then.
I believe the last time the project was in .NET Core 2.1 and this is running .NET 5, don't know if that has an impact on how the code should be implemented.

Been struggling with this for several hours, I just need to get this to work, so I implement a cleaner way to have multiple posts buttons on one form instead of the single submit. You don't wanna know what they've been doing so far.

Comment: Are you able to tranform your query string data into an object before the ajax request?  The controller method is expecting an object, no?
`data: {'Id': 911234567, 'Language': 'nl', 'FirstName': 'Jeff'}`

Answer (score 0):

you need to post  antiforgerytoken validation since you have it in your action, add to ajax

```
 headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken:
$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
```

or remove an antiforgerytoken validation from the action

also redirect is not exist in a response, try

```
....
if (data) {
            window.location.replace(data);
}
....
```

Comment: Indeed some issues with handling the redirects, but I'll sort that out.
Need to find an indication when something is a redirect response or a regular view response

Answer (score -1):

If you debug the controller you can use this.HttpContext in the immediate window to check what's been passed though  e.g.

```
?this.HttpContext.Request.Form
or 
?this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString
or
?new StreamReader(this.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync().Result
```

it's likely the data doesn't match the HomeModelView object, you could also add a bind to the controller action

```
public IActionResult CurrentDossier([Bind("PropertyNameInModel,AnotherPropertyNameInModel") HomeViewModel model)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: The data was indeed in the context. Apparently the issue lied somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I bet what you are looking for is to send the whole model thru AJAX post. In that case your data parameter of AJAX should look like:

```
 data: JSON.stringify(data);
```

[Json.Stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts the object to JSON String and controller can recognize that JSON and will map your object properties to it

Answer (score -1):

First you need to update your ajax data section by convert data to JSON string as shown below i .e.

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
   data: jsonData ,
   success: function (data) {
    if (data.redirect) {
        window.location.replace(data.redirect);
     } else {
        $(dest).replaceWith(data);
     }
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    //alert('Response code:' + xhr.status + '\r\n[Error:' + err + '] ' + status);
   }
});
```

then in your controller action change the method parameter from HomeViewModel to string i.e.

```
public IActionResult CurrentDossier(string data)
```

Then inside that method convert JSON string to HomeViewModel i.e.

```
public IActionResult CurrentDossier(string data)
{
   HomeViewModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HomeViewModel>(data);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Stringifying the data did gave a weird result, it resulted in the string:
""Id=91123456789&Language=nl&UserFirstName=Jeff&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8...""

Comment: Change your content-type to application/json

Comment: It's not good practice to send object data via URL parameter

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue, it didn't had anything to do with the controller or the jQuery.
Aparrently it only works when the Properties have actual getters & setters.
Originally my viewmodel was written like:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string Id;
    public string UserFirstName;
    public string Language;
    public string __RequestVerificationToken;
    public List<DossierViewModel> Dossiers;
    ...
}
```

But it worked when written like this:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public List<DossierViewModel> Dossiers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help and effort.

Comment: glad you sussed it in the end, it's one of that easy to make mistakes that drive to crazy and that you kick yourself for afterwards lol

Comment: Glad you found it . Could have saved you & others some time if the model class was added to your original question.